# Is there 2 options to install mysql? and Have Ubuntu decided to maintain up to date mysql with the latest version in his 16.04 Xenial repositories?

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, mysql

I have installed mysql from the official ubuntu repository, runing [this commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html).

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Even you can install mysql-workbench. And this is the version, and yes it is the latest.

```
peter@peter-desktop:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

In the mysql documentation you can install it by installing his [mysql apt repositories](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-install-components).

Then, It is a matter of personal preferences or is there some other matter?
If it exist, please share with us the details.

I ask this, because this surprises me that mysql has being up to date in ubuntu 16.04 LTS xenial repositories.

Comment: why git or python or mongodb is not  up to date too in ubuntu 16.04 LTS .  And why mysql does up to date ?

Comment: How often mysql take his updates?

Answer (score 0):

About your question and your comments:

It is just how do you prefer to install the package, for example:

- To install a CLI Music Player called Tizonia (That I recently heard about and liked it a lot) you can install it in the folowing ways:

  - Executing `curl -kL https://github.com/tizonia/tizonia-openmax-il/raw/master/tools/install.sh | bash`.
  - Downloading the *.deb file from [here](https://bintray.com/tizonia/ubuntu).
  - Installing using `sudo snap install tizonia`.
  - You can clone the [Github Repo](https://github.com/tizonia/tizonia-openmax-il) and install it from source.

All those ways lead to the same destination, have installed Tizonia in your computer and working.

For MySQL it's the same thing, also you can download the source code and compile it in your own machine. While we are talking mysql is developing an experimental release of MySQL for the snap universal Linux package system, yet another way to install packages in Ubuntu.

For the 2nd question in your comments, here is your answer: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I ask this, because this surprises me that mysql has being up to date in ubuntu 16.04 LTS xenial repositories.

Comment: It is not only in that version, [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql-server) you can see more details.

Comment: (metapackage depending on the latest version) , It is the key. And mysql had changes from 2016-04 beginning with version [5.7.12 to now 5.7.20](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/)